# Firebase getReferenceFromUrl()- что входит в параметр

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-android

Подскажите что входит в строчном параметре и что такое "gs://"?

```
StorageReference storageRef = storage.getReferenceFromUrl("gs://<your-bucket-name>");
```

Первая же строчка кода в документации Firebase https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/android/create-reference

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`gs://` - это просто схема, аналог `http://`, `ftp://` etc. В данном случае, думаю, не важно что оно значит. Возможно это просто сделано гуглом для наглядности ибо, видимо, расшифровывается как `GoogleStorage` и в их внутренних процессах просто призвано, видимо, разделять ссылки по назначению.

В вашем случае, как и описано в доке по вашей ссылке вам надо перейти в консоль, в нужный проект, во вкладку `storage` и скопировать указанный там адрес вида `gs://АДРЕС_ПРОЕКТА.appspot.com`

Вот скрин:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]